Python Debugging is too slow? How to make it the debugging faster?
import time
from uuid import uuid4

a=[uuid4() for i in range(20000)]
b=a[:19000]+[uuid4() for i in range(1000)]
start=time.time()
c=[i for i in a if i in b]
print(c)
print(time.time()-start)
print("debug point here")

Running the above code in Intellij with Run config
it outputs
17.317973613739014
debug point here

Running the above code in Intellij with Debug config
it outputs
143.317973613739014
debug point here

Why is this difference of 9x in debug mode? How to improve this? Almost similar results while debugging in VSCode

Why not simply make both ways thousands of times faster? Or did you make this slow on purpose to demonstrate debug's additional slowness?

Hello, this could be the problem, I've raised the issue on GitHub. I think can get a reply soon.
